# Synchronizing multiple AKPlayers

Tags: swift, xcode, audiokit

I've been struggling with this for a while. I've got an array of AKPlayers.

```
var players = [AKPlayer]()
```

I've searched many and many other questions online about the same issue, and they all suggest using: `AKPlayer.play(atTime: AVAudioTime)`

I've tried this by doing (and other similar tries):

```
    var sampleRate = selectedSong!.channels[0].audioFile!.sampleRate
    var sampleTime = players[0].audioTime(at: players[0].currentTime)?.sampleTime
    var startTime = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: sampleTime! + Int64(0.25*sampleRate), atRate: sampleRate)

    for audioPlayer in players {
        audioPlayer.play(at: startTime)
    }
```

and other similar things like:

```
 for audioPlayer in players {
     audioPlayer.play(when: 0, hostTime: mach_absolute_time())
 }
```

but none of them worked. There is a noticeable difference between the playback times. (The AudioFiles are of the same length, same format).

If it is helpful, my setup is as follows:

```
AKPlayer -> AKPitchShifter 
                            > AKMixer > AudioKit.output
                  AKPlayer
```

** All the `AKPlayer`s above were appended to the `players` array.

Maybe this is due to my lack of understanding about what `AVAudioTime` is and how it works.

Thanks in advance.

******* NOTES ******
The [docs](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/develop/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Playback/Player/AKPlayer.swift) for `AKPlayer` say

> Players can be locked to a common
>    clock as well as video by using hostTime in the various play functions

But does not provide an example for syncing to hostTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track.  You just need to get the current time, rather than retrieving it from using audioTime(at:) which is only useful on an already playing player.

```
// .now() is a convenience extension and AVAudioTime + Double is overloaded.
var startTime = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.25
```

If the arbitrary 0.25 buffer isn't cutting it, try looping through your players calling `player.prepare()` before getting `now()` for scheduling start.

Comment: Could you explain your implementation of the .now() extension a bit more extensively? The last portion of ‘AudioTime + Double is overloaded’ is causing some confusion for me.

Comment: Never mind. With some testing, I found it out. I've edited your post to include it for future people to be able to find it. If there is a better implementation, please change it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I use mr. Dave234 solution the first play is sync but it seems the second loop has a little noticeable delay. here is my code.

```
playerOne.looping = true
playerTwo.looping = true
playerThree.looping = true
playerFour.looping = true
playerFive.looping = true

let startTime = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.25
playerOne.play(at: startTime)
playerTwo.play(at: startTime)
playerThree.play(at: startTime)
playerFour.play(at: startTime)
playerFive.play(at: startTime)
```

Comment: Try calling prepare() on the players before acquiring startTime.

Comment: Do you mean schedule(from:,to:,avTime:)? AKAudioPlayers doesn't have prepare() function

Comment: AKAudioPlayer is being replaced with AKPlayer.

Comment: use player.buffering = .always for seamless looping.